# I need some help for a parametrization

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Calculate the next integral

$$\int_\gamma \left(\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}, \frac{-x}{x^2+y^2}\right) $$ where $\gamma$ is the curve $x^6+y^6=1$.

I need some help to get a good parametrization of $\gamma$, any suggestions?

Comment: Try $ x = \cos^{1/3} \theta, \quad y = \sin^{1/3} \theta $?

Answer (score 0):

The equation $x^6+y^6=1$ represents a set of points, not a curve.  You may parametrize that set in different ways and depending on your parametrization the value of the integral (which is the winding number of the curve) varies.

Comment: Can you give me a couple of parametrizations to check your affirmation?

Comment: isn't $x^6+y^6 = 1$ is a closed curved?